# How to convert date 2021-04-01T00:12:02+00:00 in date 2021-04-01012:02:00 in dataframe pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I Try convert `2021-04-01T00:12:02+00:00` in

```py
df.withColumn(,'nwe_date',to_timestamp(col('column1.date_modified'), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))
```

But it is not working, I am in Brazil, I need the time zone to be the one here, can anybody help me?

Comment: The "dd" substitution - meant for double digit days - does not convert 01T00. Also your format says there must be a space.. The format string is incompatible with your date string.. I would not know a date format string that could translate the above, that is why this is a comment, not an answer. You could substitute using a RegEx expression first ? To filter the relevant things ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below code.

To parse timestamp use this `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss` format.

```
df.withColumn("new_date",to_timestamp(col("dt"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"))
```

```
+-------------------------+-------------------+
|dt                       |new_date           |
+-------------------------+-------------------+
|2021-04-01T00:12:02+00:00|2021-04-01 00:12:02|
+-------------------------+-------------------+
```

To get `2021-04-01012:02:00` output.

```
df.withColumn("parsed_date",to_timestamp(col("dt"),"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")).withColumn("new_date",regexp_replace(col("parsed_date")," 00:","0")).show(false)
```

```
+-------------------------+-------------------+----------------+
|dt                       |parsed_date        |new_date        |
+-------------------------+-------------------+----------------+
|2021-04-01T00:12:02+00:00|2021-04-01 00:12:02|2021-04-01012:02|
+-------------------------+-------------------+----------------+
```